# Is there is any generalize formula for this series??

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

What is the way to find out
$$\binom{n}{1^2}+\binom{n}{2^2}+\binom{n}{3^2}+\cdots $$
I know one way is to iterate over $\sqrt{n}$ and for all integer I will find $\binom{n}{i^2}$.

Comment: So you are asking for $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor {\sqrt n } \right\rfloor } \binom{n}{k^2 } ?
$$

Comment: yes the same thing you have written

Comment: Pls use MathJax.

Comment: Letting $a(n)$ be your sum, $a(n)-a(n-1)$ seems to be [A103198](https://oeis.org/A103198). Seems unlikely that there is any simple closed form for $a(n)$.